# What does "TypeError: [foo] object is not callable" mean?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of Facebook postIDs, and I am getting the following error:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Here is my code:

```
MCTOT_postIDs = [["126693553344_10155053097028345"],
["126693553344_10155050947628345"],
["126693553344_10155048566893345"],
["126693553344_10155044677673345"],
["126693553344_10155042089618345"],
["126693553344_10155035937853345"],
["126693553344_10155023046098345"]]

g = facebook.GraphAPI()
g.access_token = g.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)

for x in MCTOT_postIDs():
g.get_object('fields="message, likes, shares')
```

I know I am making a basic error somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: You just need to `for x in MCTOT_postIDs:`

Comment: If you put `()` after a variable, then you are trying to call it as a function. As the error says, a list is not callable. So drop the `()`.

Comment: Thank you!  I made the change you recommended, but I now get the following error: TypeError: get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Comment: AndrewSmith: That is a different question about using the Facebook API. We cannot debug your code line-by-line with you on Stack Overflow. Take another look at the documentation. You probably want to use the `x` value in the loop too (and have some actual code in the loop - assuming your indentation is shown correctly here?). If you cannot figure it out with half an hour of reading and trying things from the documented examples, then post another question, showing what you tried, and focusing on the next error.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: 
For the other error, the function g.get_object(...) requires one more argument, that you are not passing.
You're passing the fields, but you're must pass an ID as an argument too, you must pass the x of your loop, that contains the id.

Probably should go like:

```
g.get_object('fields="message, likes, shares', x)
```

or maybe

```
g.get_object('fields="message, likes, shares', x[0])
```

if you need to pass it as a string, not an array (your list is a list of arrays)
but this should be a topic for a new question...

---

The error message says:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

So look again at your code: when you try to do the for ... in loop, you're trying to call your list, as if it was a function.

You're doing

```
for x in MCTOT_postIDs():
```

When you should be doing

```
for x in MCTOT_postIDs:
```

The list is not callable, and the () is used for calling a function (meaning: execute the function). Remove it and it should work.